# Setting value of checkbox programmatically in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, gridviewrow

I can check the value of a checkbox in a GridViewRow:

```
isChecked = CType(row.FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox).Checked
```

But what's baking my noodle is trying to figure out how to programmatically set a checkbox to checked.

The scenario is I have some rows in a GridView that are associated to another value in a dropdown. So, when I select the value in the dropdown, I'd like the checkboxes in the GridViewRows that are associated with that value to be already checked.

Problem: The check value is not persisted in the database.  There's no field for it.  The checkbox on the GridViewRows is an ASP TemplateField.

So I iterate through the rows and would like to check whichever checkboxes I need to based on whatever condition.

Hope I was sufficiently clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this

```
CType(row.FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox).Checked = True
```

or

```
CType(row.Cells(index).Controls(controlIndex), CheckBox).Checked = True
```

Also, see the following [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145756/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052406-1.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hm, I could have sworn I tried something like your number 1 option there.. I guess it's late, I'm tired, and I must have missed something!  
I got it to work by declaring a CheckBox variable and assigning the chkSelect value to that, but I reverted back to your option above as that was what I was striving for originally.  Many thanks!